# An installation step failed. You can try to run the failing item again from the menu, or skip it and choose something else

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation

I'm having an issue installing Kali in VirtualBox from the iso. I've followed [these instructions](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-kali-linux-on-virtualbox), but I'm getting an error:

> An installation step failed. You can try to run the failing item
>   again from the menu, or skip it and choose something else. The failing
>   step is: Select and install software.

This type of question has been asked by others, but all the solutions seem to be increasing disk space, which I've done. I'm using VB 6.1.6 r137129 (Qt5.6.2) and the latest Kali

I think I'm installing a rather minimal setup. I've set up what should be plenty of RAM and hard drive space:

Setup:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Vz6.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGXYv.png

Installing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orj5C.png

Error occurs during the middle of the "select and install software" process:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKHIh.png

Comment: Welcome to U&L, please check our [guidelines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help), as a rule we don't usually post images, uploads and links are preferred. If you want a "hassle free" Kali VM install then it may be worth taking a look [here](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) and just grabbing a 'pret-a-porter' vm image than struggling with the install.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a relatively new error since most threads I fould on this topic are only a few months old, and I didn't find any answers while searching.

I tried to increase the disk space all the way to 60 GB, give the VMware 2 cores and 4 GB or RAM, but it didn't help. So it does not seem to be a resource problem but a bug with something.

I found only one way arount it: to install the pre-built VMware version of Kali from kali/downloads. Unpack dhe ZIP file and run the VM with the file you downloaded; you will instantly go straight to the login/password prompt (which is `kali`) and have access to the Kali linux tools.

**The cons are** that it is not a full version of Kali Linux, meaning I ran into a lot of missing important pentesting tools; even simple tools like `armitage` were not there.

You also will *not* have full root access to the VM, so if you type e.g. `ifconfig` it will show you "Unknown command", so make sure you use `sudo` for those commands (or become root with `sudo su`). That way, you can also install the missing tools you need.

Another problem is that it doesn't seem to have any means to save your progress, which means its useless; every work you do will be erased moment you shut it down (which sucks ...)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up just using 2019's version of Kali and it worked. I guess there have been some updates that broke the installation.

Answer (score -1):

In software selection window,
untick "default -- recommended tools" and continue.
99% this will work. If not working try unticking some other selected option and do some experiment with it. It should work.